# error when attempting to go back to normal mode in vim command-line window

Tags: vim, macvim

When I open the command-line window for editing a complex command-line in vim, I expect to be able to go back and forth in and out of insert / normal mode to edit as I would in any other buffer.  (That's the point of the command-line window, right?  So that I can do that?)  But instead, when I hit ESC to go back to normal mode, I get this:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>15_CloseStackPop:
line    3:
E11: Invalid in command-line window; <CR> executes, CTRL-C quits:         pclose
```

I'm game to try to figure this out, but I don't have a lot to go on.  `vim --noplugin` doesn't seem to have this problem, so it's clearly one of the plugins I have loaded, but which one?  I have quite a few.  "line 3" of what file?  What does "E11" mean?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that this was a bug in the ['autoclose' plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849).  I removed the reference to `pclose` from the `<SID>CloseStackPop` function, and now Escape in command-line mode works fine.

In case anyone else has this problem: functions in plugins can be defined with `<SID>`, which (in the source code) just looks like `<SID>Foo`, but to Vim look like `<SNR>4321_Foo`.  I was looking for `15_CloseStackPop`, assuming that the `<SNR>` was something special, but when I just did a `grep CloseStackPop -r ~/.vim/plugins` the offending plugin came up right away.

Comment: You probably want to change `pclose` to `silent! pclose` instead of removing it. It's responsible for closing the preview window after a completion. I had the same error from something doing the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11733388/79125

Answer (score 1):

Try Ctrl+C as a synonym for Escape. Also check .vimrc for the plugins. This isn't standard behavior for vi. If I were you I wouldn't use any plugins unless I was absolutely sure what they did. Perhaps start from scratch and reinstall the ones you feel completely sure of.

Comment: Ctrl+C doesn't seem to work as a synonym for Escape in that context; Escape goes back to Normal mode, Ctrl+C goes back to cmdline mode (as opposed to cmdwin).