# How do I prevent my vim autocmd from running in the command-line window?

Tags: vim

I use an autocommand to close the preview window when I leave insert mode as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3107159/79125). But when I am in the command-line window (`q:`), I get an error: `E11: Invalid in the command-line window; <CR> executes, CTRL-C quits: :pclose|endif`

How can I prevent this error?

I tried running `:set` in the command-line window and a regular window, but no obvious option revealed itself in the diff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `silent!` to suppress the error:

```
autocmd CursorMovedI *  if pumvisible() == 0|silent! pclose|endif
autocmd InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|silent! pclose|endif
```